# EXPORT_SYMBOL does not export symbols globally

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm running a 3.4.7 kernel on my box and writing my own kernel modules, one of which should call functions in other modules.

I used EXPORT_SYMBOL to make the functions accessible to the other kernel modules. In my case, my module 'klm_sse' does this.

Now I load another module that uses the symbols exported by 'klm_sse', but when I load it, it complains:

```
[22892.216551] klm_<...>: Unknown symbol sys_srv_register_multiple (err 0)
```

Here is the output of 'cat /proc/kallsyms | grep klm_sse', where klm_sse is my module name.

```
ffffffffa013d170 r __ksymtab_sys_srv_register_multiple  [klm_sse]
ffffffffa013d28b r __kstrtab_sys_srv_register_multiple  [klm_sse]
ffffffffa012e9b0 t sys_srv_register_multiple    [klm_sse]
```

From the 'man' pages I read that if an entry from /proc/kallsyms shows a lower case letter, here 'r' and 't', it means that the symbols are not globally exported.

How do I make my exports globally visible, so others can access it?

Is it a kernel compile option that is needed to fix this? Appreciate any inputs regarding this, I am literally banging my head on this for two days!

Thanks a million in advance

Comment: An obvious thing but - are you sure the function is not declared as static?

Comment: Concerning 't' and 'T' labels, the latter is used for all non-static functions defined in the module, if I am not mistaken, no matter whether they are exported or not. Global visibility != being exported. Besides that, could you show the relevant portions of your code? One more question: is the module that uses functions from 'klm_sse' built using appropriate symvers file?

Comment: Eugene, the functions are not at all declared as static. Regarding the other module that uses 'klm_sse', I have to investigate on that, but first of all I am trying to load 'klm_sse' and look at /proc/kallsyms with 'T'. I guess the way dependent modules are built will not affect this, right? Appreciate any other suggestions

Comment: Yes, .symvers thing does not affect how a symbol is shown in /proc/kallsyms. It is just another tricky part when using exported stuff. As for other suggestions, it is diffucult to guess what is going on without seeing the code. Could you add the relevant portions of the code to your question?

Comment: Eugene, would you like to see the Makefile or the code snippets? In the code, it's just like any other non-static function with  EXPORT_SYMBOL. Let me know what exactly you would like to see.

Comment: I think it is better to see both. Could you also specify which kernel version and variant are you using (some stock kernel from your Linux distro, the one from kernel.org, or a custom one)? If it is a kernel provided by the distro, which distro are you using? On which architecture? x86-64, I guess? If you have built the kernel yourself, did you set any specific options in the kernel config? All this info may help.

Comment: One more note. When replying to the comments, could you prefix the name of the user who you are replying to with '@' sign? This way the user will be notified of your replies.

Comment: @Eugene the problem got resolved. The issue was that I was not linking my modules with the module linker script, that is the reason, symbols were not exported. Sorry for the very late update, but your inputs were valuable.